# DynamoDB, can't save encrypted data, "not authorized to perform: kms:GenerateDataKey on resource"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, amazon-kms

I'm trying to save encrypted data to DynamoDB with the help of the "Amazon DynamoDB Encryption Client for Java".
I also use the Serverless framework to deploy my application (some Lamdba functions using DynamoDB). The AWS Lamdba functions are written in Kotlin.

I have this in my `serverless.yml` in the `iamRoleStatements` section (under the `provider` section):

   `- Effect: “Allow”
     Action:
       - “kms:GenerateDataKey”
     Resource: “*”`

I thought that it should be enough but I'm getting this error when I'm trying to save encrypted data to DynamoDB:

`com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.AWSKMSException: User: arn:aws:sts::120102300450:assumed-role/appname-username-eu-west-1-lambdaRole/appname-username-functionname is not authorized to perform: kms:GenerateDataKey on resource: arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:120102300450:key/12d3f45c-6fff-0007-b123-5bfe5678e012 (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: ...)`

(the alphanumeric IDs are obfuscated here to not disclose real data)

I also tried to add several other KMS permissions but it didn't help:

    `- Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "kms:GenerateDataKey"
        - "kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext"
        - "kms:CreateAlias"
        - "kms:CreateKey"
        - "kms:Decrypt"
        - "kms:Encrypt"
        - "kms:EnableKey"
        - "kms:UpdateAlias"
      Resource: "*"`

So, the whole purpose of the "Amazon DynamoDB Encryption Client for Java" cannot be achieved in this case.

What is missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I've found what was the problem. I used the default KMS key, and I had to use a custom key. Then it worked.

Comment: what is the custom key you used ,  is that alpha-numeric key or the alias key from KMS .

Comment: I can't remember already, I just had to use a custom KMS key, not the default one. You can try alpha-numeric for example.